# MySQL: How to Join two table and Group By based latest records for each record

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

[image]

hi, I have a problem with MySQL.
I want to group by records based on latest records
I designed my tables and desire result in above image
please help me. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get latest (inserted_date) for every PID then use that as separate table.

Eg:

```
SELECT P.PID, S.SID, P.PRODUCTNAME, S.PRICE, S.COUNT, S.INSERTED_DT FROM
PRODUCT P
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT PID, MAX(INSERTED_DATE) AS LATEST_DT FROM STOCK
) P1 ON P.PID = P1.PID
INNER JOIN STOCK S ON S.PID = P.PID AND S.INSERTED_DATE = P1.LATEST_DT
```